# Wiederholung versus Auslassung einer Negation – "kein Risiko eingehen und (nicht) ertappt werden"

Tags: difference, usage, sentence-structure, style, redundancy

Ich habe in einem Buch den folgenden Satz gelesen:

> Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und wurde nicht ertappt.

So wie der Satz steht, ist es eine Ellipse für

> Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und [hoffentlich] wurde [sie] nicht ertappt.

Als ich den Satz gelesen habe, war ich im ersten Moment aber über das *nicht* im zweiten Teil gestolpert. Erwartet hätte ich:

> Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und wurde ertappt.

Dabei handelt es dann natürlich nicht um eine Ellipse, da die Aussage nicht ist, dass "sie hoffentlich ertappt wurde".
Vielmehr sehe ich da eine engere Verknüpfung der beiden Teile "kein Risiko eingehen" und "ertappt werden", wobei letzterer Teil die unerwünschte Folge ausdrückt, welche eintreten könnte, falls der erste Teil sich bewahrheitet. Insofern wird eine Negierung des zweiten Teils 'impliziert' und macht die Verwendung von *nicht* überflüssig.

Je mehr ich aber nun darüber nachdenke, desto unsicherer werde ich, ob beide Versionen wirklich richtig sind. Auf der einen Seite kommt mir die im Buch verwendete Variante nach wie vor sehr merkwürdig vor. Auf der anderen Seite bin ich mir nicht mehr sicher, ob meine Logik korrekt ist.
Zumal man auch mal von der Situation ausgehen sollte, wo der erste Teil eine Negierung aufweist, der zweite jedoch 'positiv' (wie nennt man das richtig?) ist. Ich ändere dazu mal das Beispiel ein wenig ab. Außerdem füge ich an der Stelle noch eine weitere modifizierte Version ein:

> Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und hoffentlich wurde sie gewarnt.
>   Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und hoffentlich ist sie nach Hause gegangen.

Das Besondere beim zweiten Beispiel ist, dass sowohl der Wunsch, dass sie nach Hause gegangen ist, als auch der Wunsch, dass sie nicht nach Hause gegangen ist, (ohne weiteren Kontext) Sinn ergeben.

Gekürzt sähe es dann so aus:

> Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und wurde gewarnt.
>   Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und nach Hause gegangen.

Unter Anwendung meiner 'Denkweise' wie vorhin beschrieben, würde das rückwärts aufgelöst wie folgt lauten:

> Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und wurde nicht gewarnt.
>   Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und nicht nach Hause gegangen.

Q1: Ist es nun überhaupt richtig/stilistisch akzeptabel, bei zweifacher Negation die zweite auszulassen, natürlich unter der Voraussetzung, dass eh kein Missverständnis entsteht? Oder ist meine 'Denkweise' wie oben beschrieben schwer bis gar nicht nachvollziehbar?

Hinzu kommt nun noch, dass ich interessanterweise im zweiten modifizierten Beispiel eine leicht andere Interpretation empfinde, wenn ich das Hilfsverb *ist* auslasse bzw. wiederhole.

> Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und nach Hause gegangen.
>   Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und ist nach Hause gegangen.

Den ersten Satz interpretiere ich sofort und unmissverständlich als "hoffentlich ist sie nicht nach Hause gegangen". Beim zweiten tendiere ich leicht dazu, es als "hoffentlich ist sie nach Hause gegangen". Würde hier aber auch die andere Interpretation nachvollziehbar empfinden.

Q2: Wie interpretiert ihr die Variante mit und ohne Wiederholung des Hilfsverbs. Bilde ich mir den Unterschied nur ein? Beeinflusst die Wiederholung wirklich die Aussage des Satzes, oder anders formuliert: Kann die Auslassung tatsächlich eine stärkere Bindung suggerieren (sprich: das eine ist eine Folge des Anderen) bzw. die Wiederholung eine lockere Bindung vermitteln und das Ganze als einfache Ellipse erscheinen lassen?

---

Anmerkung: Das Ausgangsbeispiel könnte übrigens auch so geändert werden, dass es der Form meines zweiten ergänzenden Beispiels entspricht:

> Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und (nicht) ertappt worden.

Comment: Die Frage ist mal wieder viel länger geworden, als mir lieb ist. Ich hoffe, ich konnte alles einigermaßen verständlich erklären. :)

Answer (score 1):

Zunächt einmal ist der Ausgangssatz meiner Auffassung nach nicht ganz richtig. Ich denke, wenn das Verb aus dem ersten Teil im zweiten ersetzt wird, muss das Subjekt wiederholt werden, also:

> Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und wurde sie nicht ertappt.

Es geht auch:

> Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und nicht ertappt worden.

Soll das "nicht" im zweiten Teil eingespart werden, muss es auch im ersten stehen, dass dort eine andere Verneinung steht, genügt nicht:

> Hoffentlich ist sie nicht ein Risiko eingegangen und ertappt worden.

Das erscheint mir sogar fast eindeutig, da man, wenn man

> Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und ist sie ertappt worden.

meinte, ja

> Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und ertappt worden.

schreiben würde.

Answer (score 0):

Zur Frage 1:
"Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und wurde ertappt" geht aus zwei Gründen nicht.

1. "kein" hat negierende Funktion für ein Substantiv, aber nicht für ein Verb. Man kommt gar nicht auf die Idee, "kein" auf "wurde ertappt" zu beziehen, und "kein" verneint auch nicht "hoffentlich". Daher ist die Aussage des zweiten Satzteils:

> Hoffentlich ... wurde (sie) ertappt.

2. Ersetzen wir also "kein Risiko" durch eine Verneinung des voranstehenden Verbs, nicht gerade elegantes Deutsch, aber immerhin möglich:

> Hoffentlich ist sie nicht ein Risiko eingegangen und wurde ertappt.

Das funktioniert immer noch nicht! Der Grund dafür ist, dass das vorangestellte "hoffentlich" nach wie vor beide Teile des Satzes regiert. Das nebenordnende "und" signalisiert, dass die beiden Aussagen gleichwertig sind. Die eine kann nicht für die andere stehen, sie müssen daher genauso genommen werden, wie sie sind:

```
Ich hoffe, dass sie... 
a. ...kein Risiko eingegangen ist und  
b. ertappt wurde.
```

Dass eigentlich gemeint war

```
Ich hoffe, dass sie
a ...kein Risiko eingegangen ist und 
b. nicht ertappt wurde.
```

was ja der beabsichtigte Sinn ist, kann ich als Leser nur aus der Sinnwidrigkeit schließen, nicht aus der Aussagelogik des Satzes.

Die doppelte Negation funktioniert nur, wenn man "und" durch "oder" ersetzt:

```
Hoffentlich ist sie nicht ein Risiko eingegangen oder wurde ertappt.
```

Es funktioniert, weil "oder" hier tut, wofür es geschaffen wurde, es zeigt eine Alternative an, und zwar zwischen "ein Risiko eingehen" und "ertappt werden". Das ist allerdings auch nicht, was der ursprüngliche Satz sagen wollte.

Es gibt also keine echte Alternative dazu, die beiden Verben getrennt zu verneinen:

> Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und wurde nicht ertappt.

Eine Möglichkeit kann ich mir doch noch vorstellen:

> Hoffentlich ist sie nicht ein Risiko eingegangen und wurde **dabei**
>   ertappt.

Das "dabei" neutralisiert mit rein semantischen Mitteln die Nebenordnung von "und wurde ertappt", bezieht es direkt auf das Risiko und schließt damit aus, dass die "Hoffnung" sich auf das "ertappen" beziehen kann.

Frage 2: "Hoffentlich ist sie kein Risiko eingegangen und nach Hause gegangen" ist grammatisch richtig, es spießt sich aber bei der Semantik. Vor allem die Dopplung "eingegangen" und "gegangen" irritiert, weil hier eine abstrakte und eine konkrete Aussage miteinander gekoppelt werden und sich dasselbe Hilfszeitwort teilen müssen. Es kollidieren zwei unterschiedliche Vorstellungswelten, mit dem Eingehen eines Risikos ist ein viel komplizierterer Vergegenwärtigungsvorgang verbunden als mit dem einfachen "nach Hause gehen". Ich würde also zumindest für "nach Hause gehen" ein eigenes Hilfszeitwort verwenden bzw. überhaupt eine andere Formulierung wählen.

Comment: Ich bin insofern nicht überzeugt, weil ich meine nicht, dass nur durch Verwendung von "dabei" es möglich wird, sondern dass das Wort nur zum Verständnis beihilft. Bei Auslassen von "dabei" kann eine Zweideutigkeit entstehen, aber der Satz würde dadurch nicht falsch (wie du im ersten Teil argumentiert hast).

Comment: Außerdem überzeugt es mich auch nicht, dass es nicht geht, weil hier die Negation einmal "kein" und einmal "nicht" ist. Ich habe versucht klarzumachen, dass die Negation des zweiten Teil insofern implizit ist, weil es als 'mögliche Folge des Unerwünschten' angesehen würde. Das "kein" aus dem ersten Teil soll dabei überhaupt keinen direkten Bezug auf den zweiten Teil nehmen. Ah, ich bin schlecht im Erklären :(

Comment: Nicht, dass man nicht verstehen würde, was gemeint ist. Aber das Verstehen wird nicht durch Syntax oder Grammatik hergestellt, sondern ausschließlich durch den Rückschluss, dass es völlig unsinnig wäre gleichzeitig zu hoffen, dass jemand kein Riskio eingeht und ertappt wird. Sobald der Kontext nicht so deutlich ist, lässt uns die Konstruktion an sich im Stich. Vielleicht fällt mir noch ein Beispiel ein, an dem das klar wird.